# Kotlin - memberProperties should include synthetic properties declared in java super class

Tags: java, kotlin

Consider the following Java class...

```java
public class JavaSuperClassWithInstanceMembers {
    private final int superClassReadonlyProperty = 0;
    private int superClassMutableProperty = 0;

    public int getSuperClassReadonlyProperty() {
        return superClassReadonlyProperty;
    }

    public int getSuperClassMutableProperty() {
        return superClassMutableProperty;
    }

    public void setSuperClassMutableProperty(int value) {
        superClassMutableProperty = value;
    }

    public void superClassInstanceFunction() {
    }
}
```

Now lets get its `memberProperties`...

```kotlin
println(JavaSuperClassWithInstanceMembers::class.memberProperties)
```

> val test.JavaSuperClassWithInstanceMembers.superClassReadonlyProperty: kotlin.Int,
>
> var test.JavaSuperClassWithInstanceMembers.superClassMutableProperty: kotlin.Int

Now consider the following Kotlin class. Notice that it extends the Java class (above)...

```kotlin
class KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers : JavaSuperClassWithInstanceMembers() {

    val subClassReadonlyProperty: Int
        get() = 0

    var subClassMutableProperty: Int
        get() = 0
        set(value: Int) {}

    fun subClassInstanceFunction() {}
}
```

Now lets get its `memberProperties`...

```kotlin
println(KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers::class.memberProperties)
```

> var test.KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers.subClassMutableProperty: kotlin.Int,
>
> val test.KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers.subClassReadonlyProperty: kotlin.Int

According to [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/member-properties.html):

> Returns non-extension properties declared in this class **and all of its superclasses.**

So why does `memberProperties` not result in the properties from the Java class too?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely strange behaviour, but exploring a bit more it seems to have nothing to do with Kotlin/Java interop. In fact, it specifically only returns a collection of *accessible* properties in the class, so it is the fact that the Java fields are private that is excluding them.

The `members` function actually makes this a lot clearer saying that it returns:

> All functions and properties accessible in this class, including those declared in this class and all of its superclasses.

---

To illustrate my point, if you make one of the properties in `KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers` private, then from a subclass `KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers2` of `KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers`, that private property is no longer included in the collection returned from either `members` or `memberProperties`.

```
open class KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers : JavaSuperClassWithInstanceMembers() {

    private val subClassReadonlyProperty: Int
        get() = 0
}
```

```
class KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers2: KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers() {

    val subClassProperty2: Int = 0
}
```

Here `KotlinSubClassWithInstanceMembers2::class.members` does not include `subClassReadonlyProperty`.